# Bootstrap: Align a label, radios and text box in a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Help!  I'm trying to align a bunch of rows in a bootstrap layout.  Each row will contain a left justified label, then 3 right justified radio buttons, and finally a right justified input box.

Here's what I've got so far the field are all there, but the layout is broken.  I want them all on one row, but it looks as if the label, radio buttons and input are all on separate rows. (see image attached)

```
![<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div>
      <label>The Field Label</label>
        <div class="input-append">
          <div class="btn-group pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="radio" qid="228" aid="130" value="0">Minimal
            </label>
           <label class="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="radio" qid="228" aid="131" value="1">Moderate
           </label>
           <label class="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="radio" qid="228" aid="132" value="2">Maximum
           </label>
          <input comment="1" optional="1" class="form-control input-small" type="number"              
              placeholder="# of People" qid="228" aid="117" value="">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>]
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbibD.png)

Comment: Why have you got radio inputs within label tags? Labels are text elements, not containers. Also try adding the "for" attribute to the labels (which should contain the text you want, not the elements).

Comment: Following this example (scroll to radio button example) http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've ended up doing, love to know if there's a better way...

Added custom styles for the question label and input field

```
input.custom {
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

input.custom:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}

div.question {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here's the HTML, using a btn-toolbar to group

```
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <div class='question'>Testing 123</div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle='buttons'>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input class='custom' type='number' placeholder='# of people'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this closer to what you're after?
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4259/

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div>
          <label>The Field Label</label>
            <div class="input-append">
              <div class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="" for='1'>Minimal</label>
                  <input id='1' name='1' type="radio" qid="228" aid="130" value="0"></input>

               <label for="2" class="">Moderate</label>
                  <input id="2" type="radio" qid="228" aid="131" value="1"></input>

               <label class="">Maximum</label>
                  <input type="radio" qid="228" aid="132" value="2"></input>

              <input comment="1" optional="1" class="form-control input-small" type="number"              
                  placeholder="# of People" qid="228" aid="117" value=""></input>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful now the radio buttons and input appear on the same line.  I'm looking for 2 improvements. 1) Use the styled radio buttons as in my original post (see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons and the sample image) and 2) put the label and all radio / inputs on the same line.